# Python's excel2img package not working with MS office 2016

Tags: python, ms-office

Using excel2img package to take scrrenshot of excel.

Recently upgraded MS office version to 2016 from 2013.

Pyhton's package "excel2img" worked with MSoffice 2013 but observing mentioned error for MS Office version 2016,not sure about the issue.Kindly guide.Thanks!

import excel2img

```
excel2img.export_img("test.xlsx", "status.png", "Sheet1", None)
```

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\excel2img\excel2img.py", line 113, in export_img
    for shape in rng.parent.Shapes: pass
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 473, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'parent'

Answer (score 1):

@May0021 Even I was searching for the same, but looks like excel2img doesnot support 2016 as per the below data.
[Excel2img requirement](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9ce76f16-2c0c-4ff1-93b3-b2228fc24c20/need-information-pythons-package-excel2img-not-working-for-microsoft-2016?forum=officeitproprevious)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else landing on this question from a Google search, https://github.com/glexey/excel2img/issues/14 explains the problem: in the Excel 2016 file format, the attribute `parent` was changed to `Parent`. Since Python is case-sensitive, it cannot find the appropriate attribute.

There is a single line in the source code for `excel2img` that needs to be changed:

`for shape in rng.Parent.Shapes: pass`

https://github.com/amfor/excel2img is a fork of the original `excel2img` that accomplishes this change.