# excel2img gives error "object has no attribute 'parent' "when used 2nd time

Tags: python-3.x

When using `excel2img` library to take snap of a specific section of a sheet , It is giving below error.

```
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.Range instance at 0x2697515534376>' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

The same code worked when used for first time. But it stopped working after that. Just to specify, I am using the same office version as earlier, the only change that I did in between is I installed few Libraries. I dont know if it is due to that.

I tried to change the excel version to `.xlsx` from `.xls`. But then it is returning error

```
"OSError: Failed to open snap.xlsx".
```

Below is the code which I am using:

```
import excel2img

excel2img.export_img("snap.xls","alarm_BB1.png","Sheet1!A2:Q20")
excel2img.export_img("snap.xls","VSWR_BB1.png","","Sheet2!A2:Q50")
excel2img.export_img("snap.xls","alarm_BB2.png","","Sheet3!A2:Q20")
excel2img.export_img("snap.xls","VSWR_BB2.png","","Sheet4!A2:Q50")
```

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
 AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object 
 Library.Range instance at 0x2697515188064>' object has no attribute 
 'parent'
```

Below is the snap excel file.both in `xls` and `xlsx` format.[snap.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kgSZXQ9K-tiNHnOr3k49E3bqcMk7Do3X/view?usp=sharing)

[snap.xls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WH1OGTKO6Df49TF_e4INK8A1QXE9TX0l/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: some questions:
1st: what python version do you use?

2nd: can you add your file? Then I could test your code with your file.

3rd: Whats the extension of your file: you wrote XLSX and in your code the file extension is XLS.

4th: what office version do you use?

Comment: @droebi:1st:My python version is 3.7.3, 2nd: Both xls and xlsx file added to question body. 3rd:Initially I tried using .xls which gave error "object has no attribute 'parent'. But when tried using .xlsx file excel2img is not able to open the excel.OSError: Failed to open snap.xlsx".4th:- Office 2016. Thanks

Comment: thx for your reply, i wrote an answer with my test results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using XLS file:

```
import excel2img

excel2img.export_img("snap.xls", "alarm_BB1.png", "Sheet1", "A2:Q20")
excel2img.export_img("snap.xls", "VSWR_BB1.png", "Sheet2", "A2:Q50")
excel2img.export_img("snap.xls", "alarm_BB2.png", "Sheet3", "A2:Q20")
excel2img.export_img("snap.xls", "VSWR_BB2.png", "Sheet4", "A2:Q50")
```

This works on my system: python 3.6 / Office 2013

I also tried the XLSX files, but these i cannot open, eventually the files are corrupt. excel2img supports XLSX files, i use this module on a project with this extension.

If I use Python 3.7 I get a module error (win32api) and if you look on the project site: there is no support listed for python 3.7 https://pypi.org/project/excel2img/

Try Python 3.6 for your project.
On another thread I read that office 2016 can be a problem for excel2img, too.
[Python's excel2img package not working with MS office 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173575/pythons-excel2img-package-not-working-with-ms-office-2016)

But this i can't test...

I hope this helps you.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept and upvote my answer ;-)